# images fetched from server are not appearing in browser?

Tags: server, lamp, lock

I am using xampp and uploading images to my directory(lampp/htdocs)  as well as in the database. 
images are showing in the folder but appears in the browser while fetching the image from database(server)?
a lock showing in images.

Comment: Please run `ls -l /path/to/images` so we see who owns them, perhaps `root`?

Answer (score 0):

The image permissions are not in order meaning you don't have permission to view them or you don't belong to the group that does. Do `ls -l /path/to/image(s)` to see the ownership and permission. Then change either ownership and or permissions of the same or add yourself to that group to have the required permissions.

Do the following:

1. Add yourself to the `xamppusers` group:

   ```
   usermod -a -G xamppusers $USER
   ```
2. Set the correct permissions on the `/opt/lampp/htdocs` folder

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 775 /opt/lampp/htdocs
   ```
3. Restart you system and add imags again to see if it works.